# How to access ViewData from HttpContext? (ASP.Net MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I don't if this is the right approach, but correct the question if necessary.

I need to access an object through the full page life-cycle that I want to create just once. I thought of using ViewData, but all my extension methods that are accessing context information are using HttpContextBase and thought I should the same for this.

Should I?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want your object to live for a single request only then you can use [HttpContextBase.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.items.aspx).

Comment: Yes, Ben, I thought of that, but since it had no setter I made the mistake of ignoring several times. Will confirm that it works when I get home and mark it.

Comment: Yeh its just a dictionary so `httpContext.Items["foo"]` will work fine.

Comment: Yeah, no need to test really! BTW do you know what's the advantage of using ViewData over HttpContextBase.Items?

Comment: ViewData is easier to work with in the context of ASP.NET MVC. If it's available then I would advise using it. Also ViewBag uses ViewData under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

Use `@ViewContext.Controller.ViewData` to access the `ViewData` of the current controller. Assuming you want to pull this from the View you're currently in. It would help to see a use-case.

`ViewData` is part of the `WebViewPage` and not really something that can be access from `HttpContextBase` itself.

After reading your comment on the other answer you could use `HttpContext.Current.Items` to create items that are only available for the current request.

Comment: Thanks BuildStart, but the answer I was looking for (probably it's impossible) is how to access ViewData from HttpContext +1

Comment: @Fabio - you can't. `HttpContext` is *ASP.NET*, but `ViewData` is *ASP.NET MVC*. That's why MVC implemented `ViewContext` to wrap the `HttpContext`.

Comment: Thanks @RPM19841. Makes perfect sense!

Answer (score -3):

You can use a Session to store the information and have it available.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but the purpose here is to have the object only for one single page life-cycle (without having to create it and delete or overwriting it on every page request although that seems the only option for now.